# Is there an advantage to using LazyCache as a service?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor-server-side, lazycache

LazyService describes how to use it directly [or as a service](https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache/wiki/Quickstart). I'm still somewhat new to the whole concept of Dependency Injection and so I'm curious.

Calling it directly (not going the DI route) is a lot simpler & easier. So why would you instead go the DI approach? The document it as an option so I'm guessing there are advantages and I'd like to understand them.

The only advantage that occurred to me is you can then use a different library. But the use of LazyService is built around `GetOrAddAsync()` and I don't think any replacement would have that.

Comment: Well, couple of benefit it might provide, It has a developer-friendly generics based API and provides a thread-safe cache implementation that guarantees to only execute your cachable delegates once. Under the hood it supports Microsoft.Extensions.Caching to provide performance and reliability in heavy load scenarios. Another crucial side is, by injecting LazyCache as a service, you decouple your code from the specific implementation of caching. This means you can easily swap out LazyCache for another caching library or service without needing to modify the consuming code.